# How to sort orders by timestamps?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sorting, mern

I want my recent order at the top
I am trying

```
Order.find({ userID: req.params.id })
.sort({'timestamps': -1})
```

but it dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have added sample code for you which I have done on *mongo shell*. You can do it same way.

Following is the sample data document with collection name `people` in the database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540411ad84317971f11dc3"), "name" : "john", "age" : 24, "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540457ad84317971f11dc4"), "name" : "sarah", "age" : 15, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540536ad84317971f11dc5"), "name" : "jimmy", "age" : 19, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540583ad84317971f11dc6"), "name" : "sashi", "age" : 20, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6054074fad84317971f11dc7"), "name" : "kevin", "age" : 39, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540760ad84317971f11dc8"), "name" : "daisy", "age" : 5, "city" : "WA", "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540786ad84317971f11dc9"), "name" : "kevin vien", "age" : 25, "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60540791ad84317971f11dca"), "name" : "sara", "age" : 24, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("605554facebf6a49ed5b6e97"), "name" : "chloe", "city" : "LA", "age" : 56, "mothertoungue" : "english", "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60593aec8658728413dd21bf"), "name" : "brett", "age" : 28, "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60593afb8658728413dd21c0"), "name" : "matt", "age" : 28, "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60593b0c8658728413dd21c1"), "name" : "george", "age" : 29, "gender" : "female" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60593b1d8658728413dd21c2"), "name" : "cassindra", "age" : 22, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60593b2a8658728413dd21c3"), "name" : "daisy pies", "age" : 49, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60593b3e8658728413dd21c4"), "name" : "john dion", "age" : 47, "gender" : "male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("605a914f5cc4ed47147fa728"), "name" : "dweyn", "city" : "tokyo", "gender" : "female", "age" : 23 }
```

So, if you sort for the above then the code would be as below:

```
db.people.find({'gender':'female'},{name:1,age:1,_id:0,gender:1}).sort({age:-1})
```

This perfectly work fine for me. It should for you as well.